# File drop is being picked by the wrong automation due to similar names

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

We have an Import Customer automation which runs every hour via SFTP file drop - FileName Pattern SFMC_CUSTOMERS_10312023040011.csv and populates our customer DE.
We have another file drop automation running for a birthday campaign - Filename Pattern begins with SFMC_CUSTOMERS_BIRTHDAY_1102201340001232.csv

Whenever the campaign file is dropped, it is being picked up by the Import Customer Automation instead of the birthday campaign. Has anyone faced a similar issue?

How can I avoid this from happening, any priority I can set apart from changing filenames.

Comment: Can you share both filename patterns you're using on both automations? Are you using CONTAINS?

Comment: If you don't want to change the filenames or the logic for triggering it, you just need to create another directory/folder in the SFTP and target that folder for the Birthday campaign. This way there is no worry on cross triggering as its 2 different locations they are looking for the file.

Comment: Thanks @Gortonington this is a good workaround. however we have asked to rename the files now.

Comment: Hi @RachidMamai yes Customer import had "contains", but even after changing that to Begins with - file drop was not working. This issue was happening in only one specific BU not all, which was weird (PS All BUs had same config). After a week we noticed the same issue happening with another campaign and not the birthday one this time. Thus we changed the filename altogether to avoid further issues and delaying our time sensitive comms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks both for providing your inputs. To summarise we have 2 options to resolve this issue -

1. Follow proper naming conventions for file drops say starting with campaign name first and avoid using same/generic starting name.
2. Or change the FTP folder where file is dropped. We couldn't use this because we have several campaigns active and many more in pipeline to go live, even though it required a change in workflow from source system dev team, but changing the file name pattern was a fool proof method.